# Jquery does not work in live version asp.net page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

So I have this little js code to animate the images (nothing fancy)

```
    $(".afbeelding").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({ width: '120%' }, 500);
    }, function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({ width: '120%' }, 500);
    });
    $(".afbeelding").mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({ width: '100%' }, 500);
    }, function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({ width: '100%' }, 500);
    });
```

This works perfectly when put in a jsFiddle.

But somehow when I try to put it in the real site, the images do not animate.

I used asp.net and vb for this site.

This is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZvjxV/1/
And this is the page: http://www.vannooijen.com/NL/collectie.aspx

Is there something that blocks it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I view the source code of your site and I recognize that there is no element has class name `afbeelding`, just double check on that.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you did not put the binding of event in document.ready You need to put in [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) to ensure the elements are added to DOM before being accessed. Also check you do not have any element with class `afbeelding`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".afbeelding").mouseenter(function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({ width: '120%' }, 500);
        }, function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({ width: '120%' }, 500);
        });
        $(".afbeelding").mouseleave(function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({ width: '100%' }, 500);
        }, function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({ width: '100%' }, 500);
        });
});
```

> The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the
>   DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other
>   event handlers and run other jQuery code. When using scripts that rely
>   on the value of CSS style properties, it's important to reference
>   external stylesheets or embed style elements before referencing the
>   scripts, [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: No... that's not it. I think it cant find the class at all..
This goes beyond the javascript

Comment: Believe me, that's not it. I already added the document.ready to be sure. But it still is not working. I really think it has something to do with it not being able to find the class.

Comment: Yes I think you need to correct both, add class to respected element and put script in doucment.ready

Comment: Did it and it works. Either way thank you both. Stupid mistake. I really thought I added the class... btw the js works without document.ready in the jsFiddle

Answer (score 1):

On your site is not working because you do not have set the class (`class="afbeelding"`) on the `input` control that hold the images, and so the script is not find this image to attach to them.

You can easily spot it by yourself just by using the browser debug tools.

Comment: Sorry can you clarify this for me? I do not understand it completly

Comment: @OussamaDooby The code that you use to capture the mouse enter, is capture the controls that have the `class=afbeelding`.

Answer (score 1):

you are loading two jquery versions in the live site (1.5.1 AND 1.9.1)

```
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.5.1.js
```

and

```
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js
```

remove 1.5.1 library

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed that there is 2 instance of jquery. Maybe you try to use jQuery.noConflict()